# Ubuntu 22.04 freezing in login screen after graphic drivers change attempt

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Lenovo LEGION 5 with a GTX 4050 graphics card. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 with Dual boot (Windows was preinstalled) many months ago and at first the default drivers worked ok with the laptop's original screen, but I couldn't plug any external monitor.

So I followed [this guide](https://devicetests.com/install-nvidia-driver-secure-boot-ubuntu) to manually install NVIDIA drivers, because no other method would work, presumably because of the secure boot being enabled.

After a couple of attempts, I managed to install the driver and everything worked like a charm: the built in display, but also the two external monitors I plugged every day.

One random day, the external monitors began randomly freezing, so I tried to uninstall and reinstall back again the driver but after the installation there is a problem: Ubuntu is freezing in the login screen. It doesn't respond to any input (built-in mouse, built-in keyboard, external mouse, external keyboard) and I can see the log in screen perfectly, and the cursor standing still, but everything is frozen.

What I've tried:

- Uninstalling every manually installed driver and going back to the original one. In this case, the login screen freezes in the built in display.
- Installing different versions of propietary drivers following the guide I linked above. In this case, when the installation is succesfull and I reboot, the login screen freezes in the external monitor.
- Disabling secure boot and doing both things mentioned above.
- Changing from dynamic to discrete graphics in the boot options.

Every step mentioned gives the same result, the frozen login screen.

Two more things to take into account, if someone can help me:

- It seems that the screen is not the actual problem, because after some time of inactivity it deems and then turns off. The problem seems to be the input methods.
- If I select "Ubuntu (advanded options)" in the grub menu, and I choose recovery mode and then the first option "resume normal boot", I can then use CTRL+ALT+F2 to start a TTY session. So I can access logs, install/uninstall staff, etc, in case that's useful.

Comment: From your tty can you edit your grub?

Comment: Yes, I can also press "E" while in the grub menu and edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts and trying many different things, I managed to get it back to normal without having to reinstall Ubuntu (which is what I wanted to avoid) following these steps:

#### 1) Remove all proprietary drivers:

a) `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

b) `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

c) `sudo apt-get update`

d) `sudo bash ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-*.run --uninstall`
If for some reason the above doesn't work, you might have to remove them manually by finding where the installer placed them, which is typically under `/usr/lib/nvidia` and `/usr/lib32/nvidia.`

#### 2) Reinstall Nouveau Driver:

```
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau --reinstall`
```

#### 3) Remove Xorg.conf:

If an Xorg configuration file was created for Nvidia, it might interfere with Nouveau. You should move or delete this file:

```
`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup`
```

#### 4) Reenable Nouveau:

Nouveau may be blacklisted within the modprobe configuration. You need to remove any blacklist files related to Nouveau:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-*.conf
```

#### 5) Recompile the Kernel Image (if necessary):

This step is typically not required, but if you've made changes to the kernel or are advised by a specific error message, you can recompile the kernel image:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

#### 6) Restart the Display Manager:

Restart your display manager to apply changes. For GDM:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

---

At this point I restarted the computer and the frozen login screen was gone, but after the Ubuntu loading screen, I got a screen with a blinking hyphen, rather than the normal login screen.

A blinking cursor on a black screen after boot typically indicates that the system is unable to start the graphical interface. **But with CTRL+ALT+F2 I was able to start a TTY session.**

From there:

#### 1) Check if Nouveau is Loaded:

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
```

If it's not listed, try to load it manually:

```
sudo modprobe nouveau
```

#### 2) Reconfigure the Display Manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

#### 3) Check the Xorg Configuration:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

#### 4) Reinstall the Desktop Environment:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

#### 5) Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

After this reboot, everything went back to normal. I had my normal login screen, this time working OK, with every input method working, etc.